# Assertion Test For Average

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a skeleton provided to write a working implementation.

I must not leave any functions in the skeleton unused. Test that if implementation works.

Specifically -- if I test it, should be able to just press the [Run] button and see convincing evidence that your code works, because of:

a) the categorical reasoning displayed by your tests
b) the line(s) of output in the console log saying "passed" coming from those tests

So far here's my codes:

```
function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
if(actual !== expected){
    console.error( "FAIL [" + testName + "] Expected \"" + expected + ", \" but got \"" + actual + "\"");
  } else {
    console.info( "SUCCESS [" + testName + "]");
  }
}


var numbers = [1, 3, 5];

function average(numbers) {
  // process array of numbers
  numbers.reduce(function(total, item){
    return total + item / numbers.length - 1;
  }, 0);
}

function sum(numbers) {
   numbers.reduce(function(total, item){
    return total + item;
  }, 0);
}



var avg = average(numbers);
console.log(avg);

var total = sum(numbers);
console.log(total);


assertEqual(avg, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
assertEqual(sum, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
```

Any idea what am I missing? is this all correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions do not return any value, just add return statements like so :

```
function average(numbers) {
 // process array of numbers
  return numbers.reduce(function(total, item){ 
    return total + item / numbers.length - 1; 
  }, 0); 
}


function sum(numbers) { 
  return numbers.reduce(function(total, item){ 
    return total + item;
  }, 0); 
}
```